# Should we have a tag for (La)TeX?

Tags: discussion

I know that LaTeX is not a part of linguistics, but I'm sure many people do use LaTeX to write up papers on linguistics and it is a useful tool (see [this Answer](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3480/do-you-have-a-vowel-trapezoid-for-spanish/3487#3487) where I created a Vowel Trapezoid). There is a specific Tex.se, but I find that a little bit of linguistic expertise could be useful there.

Answer (score 1):

If a specific question treats about Linguistics and Latex, well, why not tag with it? No problem as long as it's relevant (and the question is not *only* about Latex, and in that case it would belong to Tex SE).

Note however that that question should not be tagged with [latex](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latex) since the question is not about Latex and we tag questions not answers. You did provide a solution with Latex but the question was asking for a picture basically and it could have been provided in several ways.

Comment: Thanks, I was just linking to that answer as it included LaTeX and was an example of how useful it can be.

Comment: @DangerFourpence Ah got it. :D The rule of thumb for every tag is: if possible use existing ones. If there isn't one, create a new one but make it not too broad (linguistics would be a no, of course), not too strict. 99% you'll have a nice tag. :D

Comment: do you think this question would be ok: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3502/is-there-a-package-for-formatting-phonological-rules-in-latex ?

Comment: @DangerFourpence That's kind of borderline with Tex SE though. The point is: what kind of expertise is the question requiring? I think someone that knows Latex is more important than someone that knows Linguistics. Do you agree?

Comment: yes, perhaps, it's just that I've asked questions there in the past regarding linguistics and not had a satisfactory answer. My thinking was that a lot of people writing linguistic papers probably use tex and would encounter similar problems, like the one in my question, so _they_ might be better placed to help.

Comment: @DangerFourpence Well, it's not like it's out of place here. That's why I didn't migrate it. If you see little response you can try re-asking there later. :)